# SQL Selecting records that have dates not covered in a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am having trouble getting exactly what I need. Here are examples of my tables:

```
Plan_ID | PlanBeginDate | PlanEndDate |
    1   |    1/1/2015   |   1/1/2016  |
    2   |    1/1/2016   |   1/1/2017  |
    3   |    1/1/2013   |   1/1/2014  |
    4   |    1/1/2015   |   1/1/2016  |

SrvID  | Srv_Plan_ID | Srv_Discipline_ID | SrvBeginDate | SrvEndDate |
  1    |      1      |        1          |   1/1/2015   |   1/1/2016 |
  2    |      1      |        3          |   1/1/2015   |   1/1/2016 |
  3    |      2      |        2          |   1/1/2016   |   4/4/2016 |
  4    |      2      |        2          |   4/5/2016   |   1/1/2017 |
  5    |      3      |        1          |   1/1/2013   |   6/1/2013 |
  6    |      3      |        2          |   1/1/2013   |   1/1/2014 |
  7    |      4      |        3          |   1/1/2015   |   7/1/2016 |
  8    |      4      |        3          |   8/1/2015   |   1/1/2016 |
```

I am looking to see all plans that have dates not covered by Service dates for each distinct discipline that is related to it.

Plan 1 should not show up, as both disciplines related to it cover all of the dates.
Plan 2 should not show up, because both related services have the same discipline and together cover the entire plan date range.
Plan 3 should show up once, because SrvID 5 does not cover the entire plan date range.
Plan 4 should show up, because the month of July is uncovered for discipline 3.
I need a select statement that would return with the following fields, following the criteria above.

```
Plan_ID | PlanBeginDate | PlanEndDate |Srv_Discipline_ID | SrvBeginDate | SrvEndDate |
```

Here is what I have, so far.

```
Select Plan_ID, Srv_Discipline_ID, PlanBeginningDate, PlanEndDate, MIN(SrvBeginDate) EarliestStartDate, MAX(SrvEndDate) LatestEndDate
From dbo.Plan
JOIN Services 
    ON Plan_ID = Srv_Plan_ID
GROUP BY Plan_ID, Srv_Discipline_ID, PlanBeginDate, PlanEndDate
ORDER BY Plan_ID
```

Comment: First, is it MySQL or SQL-Server. 2nd, what did you try?

Comment: I am so sorry! This is SQL Server. 

I am new to this site and will edit my query into my original post

Comment: The query you are showing us does not seem to relate to your question. None of the column names match the tables shown.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted what I was using with my actual tables. I have updated it using the example tables I referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out one way to do this, but it involves costly recursive CTEs to expand the date ranges into individual days that can be joined against. So, to be clear, I'm not expecting performance to be very good with this query.

Note: I also fixed the `SrvEndDate` value for `SrvID = 7` from `7/1/2016` to `7/1/2015` in the test data that I used.  That must have been your intention when you said that the month of july was uncovered.

**Setup**

```
create table Plans (
  Plan_ID int not null primary key,
  PlanBeginDate date not null,
  PlanEndDate date not null
)

create table Services (
  SrvID int not null primary key,
  Srv_Plan_ID int not null,
  Srv_Discipline_ID int not null,
  SrvBeginDate date not null,
  SrvEndDate date not null
)

alter table Services
add constraint Services_fk
foreign key (Srv_Plan_ID)
references Plans(Plan_ID)

insert into Plans (Plan_ID, PlanBeginDate, PlanEndDate)
values
(1, '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01'),
(2, '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01'),
(3, '2013-01-01', '2014-01-01'),
(4, '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01')

insert into Services (SrvID, Srv_Plan_ID, Srv_Discipline_ID, SrvBeginDate, SrvEndDate)
values
(1, 1, 1, '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01'),
(2, 1, 3, '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01'),
(3, 2, 2, '2016-01-01', '2016-04-04'),
(4, 2, 2, '2016-04-05', '2017-01-01'),
(5, 3, 1, '2013-01-01', '2013-06-01'),
(6, 3, 2, '2013-01-01', '2014-01-01'),
(7, 4, 3, '2015-01-01', '2015-07-01'),
(8, 4, 3, '2015-08-01', '2016-01-01')
```

**Query**

```
with ServiceCTE as (
  select Srv_Plan_ID, Srv_Discipline_ID, SrvEndDate, SrvBeginDate as SrvDate
    from Services
   union all
  select Srv_Plan_ID, Srv_Discipline_ID, SrvEndDate, dateadd(day, 1, SrvDate) as SrvDate
    from ServiceCTE
   where SrvDate != SrvEndDate
), PlanCTE as (
  select Plan_ID, PlanEndDate, PlanBeginDate as PlanDate
    from Plans
   union all
  select Plan_ID, PlanEndDate, dateadd(day, 1, PlanDate) as PlanDate
    from PlanCTE
   where PlanDate != PlanEndDate
), UncoveredPlanDisciplineCTE as (
  select distinct pcte.Plan_ID, s.Srv_Discipline_ID
    from PlanCTE pcte
    join (select distinct Srv_Plan_ID, Srv_Discipline_ID
            from Services) s
      on s.Srv_Plan_ID = pcte.Plan_ID
   where not exists (select null
                       from ServiceCTE scte
                      where scte.Srv_Plan_ID = s.Srv_Plan_ID
                        and scte.Srv_Discipline_ID = s.Srv_Discipline_ID
                        and scte.SrvDate = pcte.PlanDate)
)
select p.Plan_ID, p.PlanBeginDate, p.PlanEndDate, 
       s.Srv_Discipline_ID, s.SrvBeginDate, s.SrvEndDate
  from UncoveredPlanDisciplineCTE c
  join Plans p
    on p.Plan_ID = c.Plan_ID
  join Services s
    on s.Srv_Plan_ID = c.Plan_ID
   and s.Srv_Discipline_ID = c.Srv_Discipline_ID
 order by p.Plan_ID, s.Srv_Discipline_ID, s.SrvBeginDate
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

**Result**

```
Plan_ID PlanBeginDate  PlanEndDate  Srv_Discipline_ID  SrvBeginDate  SrvEndDate
------- -------------  -----------  -----------------  ------------  ----------
   3     2013-01-01     2014-01-01          1           2013-01-01    2013-06-01
   4     2015-01-01     2016-01-01          3           2015-01-01    2015-07-01
   4     2015-01-01     2016-01-01          3           2015-08-01    2016-01-01
```